# Talking about the same day

Tags: tense, past-tense

I want to tell someone about the same day [current day]. For instance:

I've worked out at the gym 2 hours ago and feel good as a result [now]. Now I'm listening to music and surfing the Internet.

Are my sentences correct?

Comment: @DamkerngT. Post it, dude.

Comment: As tuespetre said, what about 'taking about the same day' concern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to check the tenses.

Because your workout was already in the past, you should say it with the past tense,

> I **worked out** at the gym 2 hours ago and it made me feel good. Now I'm listening to music and surfing the Internet.

Instead of *"it made me feel good"*, you can also just simply say,

> I feel good.

If you want to emphasize that you're feeling good at this moment, you can also say,

> I'm feeling good now.

Comment: A little more precisely: present perfect is a present tense and you cannot use it with a time adverbial which does not include the present. What you **can** say is "I have worked out within the past two hours and I feel good" -- that is a time adverbial which includes the present.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the word "today".

Comment: I suspect that OP is looking for advice on what verb constructions to use.